# Dressing immodestly versus Violating Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, tznius-modesty, orthodox

Is it a greater sin for an orthodox Jewish woman to dress immodestly or violate Shabbos?

From a halacha perspective, which one is more severe?

Comment: What about either of those verses planting Kilayim? Which of the three is more severe?

Comment: Why did you ask this question?  Your reason might help anyone thinking about answering you.

Comment: One measure of severity of a sin is the punishment for transgression.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Do you have a source that it is a sin for a Jewish woman to dress immodestly?

Comment: @YehudaW: There was an article entitled Trump Kushner Hanukkah Celebration in Hawaii. Ivanka is not dressed modestly according to halacha. She and her husband might be "modern Jews" but they observe Shabbos. Halachically, should a woman be just as careful dressing modestly as keeping Shabbos?

Comment: @RealTorah Do you know that this is the motivation for Chiddushei Torah? Is Chiddushei Torah one of your accounts? Can you cite actual halakhic literature to support your claims that Ivanka Trump is not dressed modestly according to halakha? | If you are actualy correct about Chiddushei's motivations, particularly if you are Chiddushei, consdier editing in exactly what sort of supposed halakhic violations of modesty you are referring to, as public nudity, for example [may be much more severe](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77377/8775) than other activities.

Comment: @mevaqesh: yes.

Comment: Could you be more vague? @RealTorah

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, indicate which additional info you would like.

Comment: Violating Shabbos is more severe. However, we still have to do both things at all times.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, dressing (somewhat) immodestly is not as serious a sin as not keeping Shabbat.  Here is some of my reasoning.  Immodest dress is culturally driven varying from culture, at least in part (perhaps in large part).  Keeping Shabbat is not culturally driven (or to a much smaller extent).  Violating Shabbat is a capital offense, and dressing immodestly is not.  That said, we all should try to keep all the mitzvot.  Even so, our daily prayers make it clear that everyone has difficulty keeping all the mitzvot.  It is clear to me that we all fail regularly, in many ways.

Comment: Just because something's "culturally driven" doesn't make it less severe than something not culturally driven - it's the same biblical prohibition.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin. How can culturally driven be biblical?  Pls explain.