# Eating human flesh for survival

Tags: halacha

What is the Jewish position on the choice of eating human flesh to survive in an extreme emergency situation? Would it be preferable to die of starvation while obeying the Torah or eat the only thing available if it was a deceased human body?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ephraim.

Comment: See here for in depth analysis https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77375/whats-a-better-choice-treif-meat-or-human-flesh/86552#86552 to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obligation to preserve one's life overrides any prohibition against eating human flesh. In general, Jews are allowed and encouraged to violate almost any law to save human life except the cardinal three (3) which are idolatry, immoral sexual relations, and murder. (See Gemara Sanhedrin 74a)