# Does Rashi say that cats are more Tzanua than dogs?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, rashi, tznius-modesty

My friend says there is a Rashi that says this, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The gemarra in eruvin says we would learn the concept of tsnius from cats, and elsewhere dogs are considered brazen

Comment: ^^ that's Eruvin 100b

Comment: Somewhat related:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37463

Answer (score 3):

As Robev and Double AA noted, your friend was likely referencing [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.100b.29?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) Gemara in Eruvin (100b)

> אמר רבי יוחנן: אילמלא לא ניתנה תורה, היינו למידין צניעות מחתול -
> Similarly, Rabbi Yoḥanan said: Even if the Torah had not been given,
> we would nonetheless have learned modesty from the cat...

Where [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.100b.29?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Eruvin.100b.29.1&lang2=bi) comments:

> צניעות מחתול - שאינו מטיל רעי בפני אדם ומכסה צואתו - Modesty could be
> learned from cats since they don't expel their waste before people,
> and they cover their waste.

The Gemara Beitzah (25b) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.25b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> אמר רבי שמעון בן לקיש, שלשה עזין הן: ישראל באומות, כלב בחיות, תרנגול
> בעופות. - Rabbi Shimon ben Lakish said:
> There are three brazen ones: The Jewish people among the nations;
> the dog among animals; and the rooster among birds.

Also, the Gemara Sanhedrin (108b) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108b.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en):

> ת"ר שלשה שמשו בתיבה וכולם לקו כלב ועורב וחם כלב נקשר עורב רק חם לקה
> בעורו - The Sages taught: Three engaged in
> intercourse while in the ark, and all of them were punished for doing
> so. They are: The dog, and the raven, and Cham, son of Noah. The dog
> was punished in that it is bound...

Based on Chazal's descriptions, it appears dogs are among the most brazen and exhibit the least physical self-control, which is often at odds with the trait of modesty. (How Klal Yisroel is still modest yet brazen is a separate question.)

Comment: This doesn't connect to dogs